# Send data from form to another url

Tags: php, forms, url, post, get

I want to make form for the API for another website.

Form

```
<form method=”POST” action=””>
<input type=”text” name=”type”>
<input type=”text” sender=”sender”>
</form>
```

URL of API is: 
http:// :8080/bulksms/bulksms?
username=XXXX&password=YYYYY&type=____here i want type from form_____&sender=***here i want type from form***

For Username and password values are set from the php file

example username=abc password=xyz

Help me please

Comment: sorry, i want for type charachers :" ?!. "

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you are asking, so you may need to clarify. However, you should NEVER put username and password in URL. Instead, you should use POST and https.

That said, if I understand your question correctly, to send the data as part of a URL string, you need to use "GET" as your method. Also, to send to a different URL (or page) you need to specify it in the action="" attribute.

So, something like this may be what you are after:

```
<form method="GET" action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/bulksms/bulksms">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="abc">
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="xyz">
<input type="text" name="type">
<input type="text" name="sender">
</form>
```

Not also, that you had `sender="sender"` instead of `name="sender"` which is a mistake.

If this does not answer your question please clarify what you were asking. Again, please do not send name and password as parameters in the URL like this and use https instead of http. Otherwise anyone can read the name and password quite easily.